# Pull next months data for one specific field

Tags: tableau-desktop

I have a report when I am tracking students over a 45 day period based on start date.  If a student started 8/1/2023 I want to use their student status as of that month, however when it turns to 9/1/2023 I want to use the 8/1/2023 students but pull their status for the next month.  I created a function to pull the month difference based on today() so I think I can make some formula that would say IF(MonthDateDiff = 0) THEN Student_Status ELSE.....
Not sure how to do the second part to say pull next months Student Status when MonthDateDiff = 1.

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sslqg.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. To make it easier for people to advise you, make the problem more precise. Provide a small amount of sample data, describe what results you do want to see for that sample data, and what you've tried so far.

Comment: Here is a snippet of trimmed data to show what I want the end goal to be.  Students start each month and we truncate to the 1st of the month.  This report is tracking students from start to day 45 to see their current status.  So below is a sample of a student who started 8/1/2023 with an AS status.  However in September that status has changed to DR and that is what I want to show the the DR status instead of their 8/1/2023 status of AS.

Term Start Date: 8/1/2023 - Status: AS - Term Start Date: 9/1/2023 - Status: DR

Comment: Sorry was unfamiliar with Stack Overflow formatting but I posted a quick view of what I am trying to do.  If I am looking at August I want to out the September status as their August status if that makes sense?

Comment: good step, but please edit your question to update it with the test data and more precise question. That's a lot easier for people to read -- also info in comments gets overlooked easily. Also, that way someone with a similar question later on can see the whole question and best answers and learn from your experience.

Comment: Are you trying to have this calculation expand going forward; say 45 days out from the 9/1/23 term start date to get the status of the 10/1/23 start date?

Answer (score 0):

> *pull **next months** Student Status when ...*

OK, the quote above implies that you want to write a calculated field whose value depends on the order of records when sorted according to a criteria (such as by month)

The only type of calculation in Tableau that can take the order of data into account is a **table calc**.

Table calcs are very useful and flexible but are one of the more advanced tricky parts of Tableau, unless you restrict yourself to the "easy lane" of quick table calcs.

Table calcs operate on the summary table of aggregate query results provided by the data source, based on the dimensions in play. In addition to specifying a formula, you must also specify how the summary table is partitioned and traversed - aka partitioning and addressing or compute using. Take some time to read and experiment with table calcs on easy examples first.

Alternatively, you can prepare your data to include information about related months using Tableau Prep.

Or you can use custom SQL. The SQL analog to table calcs are windowing queries, aka analytic queries.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague in a sense of what time periods are you trying to capture this info over; are you trying to calculate only 45 days out from any start date occurrence, 45 days behind from today... it is unclear and frankly unnecessary as you are truncating everything to the 1st of the month anyway. Also tableau calculations are not object oriented, so it is helpful to think of the calculations more similar to SQL rather than say python.

In that vein, if you just want the output of your image, you can just check for other existing start dates outside of a 45 day period(or one month), if it exists, just return the start minus a month. Since you always want the most recent status, just bring that dimension directly in.

A calculated field may look something like:

```
IF DATEDIFF('day',[StartDate],TODAY()) <= 45 THEN DATEADD('month', -1, [StartDate]) END
```

Just write the logic for if the start date is in the same month as today (like only 20 days out) to handle not subtracting a month and just returning [StartDate].
And you would just take the current `[StudentStatus]`.

Alex's answer is more likely correct for your case as your data may need to be restructured for you to get the desired output in Tableau.

More info on [Tableau Date Calculations](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/functions_functions_date.htm) here.